# How to create a map of pointers to member functions

Tags: c++, stdmap

I'm building a command shell for my application. My problem lies in calling the member function when a mapped command is recognized.

A complete and compact example of this shell is

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

typedef std::vector<std::string> token_list ;

class CommandShell
{
public:
    CommandShell() {}
    
    void runShell(std::ostream& out, std::istream& in);
    void cmdSave(std::ostream& out, token_list);
    void cmdLoad(std::ostream& out, token_list);
private:
    //--- important application config values stored here and modified
    //    by user commands in the shell
};

void CommandShell::cmdSave(std::ostream& out, token_list)
{
    out << "we're in the save function\n";
}

void CommandShell::cmdLoad(std::ostream& out, token_list)
{
    out << "we're in the load function\n";
}

void CommandShell::runShell(std::ostream& out, std::istream& in)
{
    //--- create the command/function map
    typedef void (CommandShell::*userCommand)(std::ostream&, std::vector<std::string>&);
    std::map<std::string, userCommand> cmd_map;
    cmd_map.emplace("save", std::mem_fn(&CommandShell::cmdSave));
    cmd_map.emplace("load", std::mem_fn(&CommandShell::cmdLoad));
    
    token_list command_and_options;  // created by parsing the whole input string
    std::string cmd_line = "";
    while (true)
    {
        in >> cmd_line;
        // tokenize the line here -- simplified for this example
        command_and_options.push_back(cmd_line);
        command_and_options.push_back("option1");
        
        if (command_and_options[0] == "quit")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            auto this_command = cmd_map.find(command_and_options[0]);
            if (this_command == cmd_map.end())
            {
                std::cout << "unrecognized command!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                //--- COMPILATION ERRORS here
                //    I've tried this...
                std::invoke((*this_command).second, this, std::cout, command_and_options);
                //    and this...
                std::invoke(this_command->second, this, std::cout, command_and_options);
                //    and this...
                //      (which actually works if I don't use member functions in the map)
                (*this_command).second(std::cout, command_and_options);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    CommandShell my_shell;
    my_shell.runShell(std::cout, std::cin);
}
```

I believe I'm close to the correct syntax, because the last version of calling the function pointer will work if I use a standalone function (not a member function). Please help me make the adjustments and understand.

Comment: Recommendation: I see `#include <functional>`. Consider using `std::function` instead of function pointers. If you MUST use function pointers, here's some excellent reading from the isocpp FAQ site: [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: You also might want to look at std::vector<std::function<void (const std::vector<std::string>&)> instead of function pointers. To store member functions you can then construct [lambda functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (capturing `this`) and put them in the map. See : [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8ahn8jvT6

Comment: @user4581301 - I've been all through the FAQ link in your comment, and my code above was the closest I could get. I knew that something was off. Thanks

Comment: @PepijnKramer - thanks for the tip about lambdas. To be honest, I've still not got my head completely wrapped around using lambdas in my day-to-day coding, but I'll get there

Comment: @MikeVine - thanks for the compilable update. It helped put it all together, along with the other answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you're storing in your map doesn't match the type you're actually placing in the map.

Your map contains raw pointers to members, but you're attempting to emplace objects returned by `std::mem_fn` into the map.  Those are different things, and are incompatible.  You need to pick one.

Either have your map contain raw `void (CommandShell::*)(std::ostream&, token_list)` pointers-to-members and call them using pointer-to-member call syntax:

```
using userCommand = void (CommandShell::*)(std::ostream&, token_list);
std::map<std::string, userCommand> cmd_map;
cmd_map.emplace("save", &CommandShell::cmdSave);
cmd_map.emplace("load", &CommandShell::cmdLoad);

// ...

(this->*(this_command->second))(out, command_and_options);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f24fea454cb4e292)

Or have your map contain `std::function` objects and use a wrapper object like `std::mem_fn`, `std::bind`, or a lambda and use "normal" call syntax:

```
using userCommand = std::function<void(CommandShell*, std::ostream&, token_list)>;
std::map<std::string, userCommand> cmd_map;
cmd_map.emplace("save", std::mem_fn(&CommandShell::cmdSave));
cmd_map.emplace("load", std::mem_fn(&CommandShell::cmdLoad));

// ...

this_command->second(this, out, command_and_options);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4e950f9f818608b)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  This answer is the closest to my existing code. I knew I was close :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::function` and `std::bind` from `<functional>`. Create a map of command names to handling functions:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::ostream&, token_list)>> commands;
commands.emplace("save", std::bind(&CommandShell::cmdSave, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
commands.emplace("load", std::bind(&CommandShell::cmdLoad, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

Then, to call a function:

```
std::string cmd_name = "save";
auto cmd = commands.find(cmd_name);
if (cmd == commands.end())
  std::cout << "unknown command!";
else
  cmd->second(std::cout, command_and_options);
```

Comment: `std::bind` is old-fashioned. Better to use a lambda

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell C++ which instance to call the member function on, even for `this` apparently:

```
(this->*(this_command->second))(std::cout, command_and_options);
^^^^^^^^                      ^
```

However, you have other compiler errors too http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60a9a8481bd5ff98